# Protocol Buffers in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, protocol-buffers

I am developing an *Angular 2* app in which I want to use Protocol Buffers to send data to a Go server.

I found this [dcodeIO/protobufjs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js). But I don't understand how should I use this in my project?

I also tried installing the typings for `protobufjs` using `typings install dt~protobufjs --global`. When I import it, WebStorm says `Cannot find module protobuf`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs#usage-with-typescript might help you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved it! I did this `npm install @types/protobufjs --save` and I got the type definitions.

Then simply used it like this `import * as ProtoBuf from 'protobufjs';`

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this! And... If you are planning using pbjs and pbts utilities to convert your protos to JS and types install the packages globally (-g npm option). I wasted some time on this. Hope it helps someone.